# insert data from csv file to mysql with sql function

Tags: mysql, csv

i'm inserting data to mysql from a csv file but i have encountred some problems becasue one of the fields includes a function of sql.Here is an example what i am trying to do. thanks.

```
id;name;ip;op
1;computer1;INET_ATON(100.0.0.1);Windows 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
"id";"name";"ip";"op"
"1";"computer1";"INET_ATON(100.0.0.1)";"Windows 7"
```

Any text enclosed by `"` will be interpreted as nothing else than a simple string by MySQL.

From the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), you can then import it as:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_csv_file.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: I have tried as you said but i got this.
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'INET_ATON(10.0.5.9)' for column 'ip' at row 1

Comment: @kamboj Indeed: `INET_ATON(10.0.5.9)` is not a `integer`. That probably means that your field `ip` is configured as an `INT` in your mysql schema.